# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am facing some issue in my project which is a Spring MVC project. In this project, for persistence layer, we are using Hibernate.

Below is my `web.xml` details:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/beanRefFactory.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When I try to run this project, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my  classpath jar details:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/ant-1.6.5.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/ant-antlr-1.6.5.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/asm-attrs.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/asm.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/aspectjweaver-1.6.9.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/c3p0-0.9.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/cglib-2.1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/cglib-2.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/commons-collections-3.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/commons-pool-1.5.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/ehcache-1.2.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/ejb3-persistence.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernate-annotations.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernate-search.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernate-validator.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/hibernate3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/jta-1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/jta.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/lucene-core-2.3.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate/oscache-2.4.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/antlr-runtime-3.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/commons-configuration-1.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/jstl.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.asm-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.context-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.context.support-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.core-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.expression-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.web-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.M3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/spring-orm-3.2.0.M1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/spring-oxm-3.2.0.M1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring/standard.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/misslenious/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar"/>
```

Any pointer or help is very appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is similar to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046654/maven-spring-dynamic-web-module-eclipse-java-lang-classnotfoundexcepti/12600686#12600686

Comment: I assume this is more of an eclipse server launcher question. If you run it in a wtp server inside eclipse (Rightclick->Run as -> Run on Server), and you don't know how the configuration is resolved, open the debug view (Window->show view->Debug (search for it)), and locate the running server. Rightclick and inspect properties to that one. It will probably have a -Dwtp.deploy= setting to point to where the webapp is being deployed. If so look inside the directory for the context/WEB-INF/lib and see if your intended libs are there.

Comment: BTW, you have duplicate libraries in your classpath. Probably don't need two versions of the same library..

Answer (score 1):

You are missing spring-web jar (spring-web-3.2.0.M2.jar) in your classpath which contains this class.

Comment: Hi Biju,If you check my class path jar details, already "org.springframework.web-3.0.0.M3.jar" is available in my class path. Any other help???

Answer (score 0):

The **ContextLoaderListener** is used to integrate Spring with web application.

To resolve ClassNotFoundException Exception perform given below steps:

1. Check Classpath for (spring-web.jar)**spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar**  (If you are running with spring 3.x, for spring spring 2.0 add
   spring.jar in classpath)
2. If you are working with Eclipse and maven make sure all dependencies are included properly on build path. (Check Java Build
   Path)
3. Cleaning your Server by selecting "Clean".

Now try to run your project.

If still you facing any issue and you are using maven based project try below given steps:

1.You need to declare maven-compiler-plugin in parent project

```
<build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
```

Make sure complied classes to be compatible with target (1.6) version.

1. Some times included project dependencies are conflicted, so to resolve conflicts perform these commands,

   mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to check if jar file is getting included in lib folder else sometimes jar files are corrupted try to download a fresh jar and include it.
2. Is it the correct path you are giving for jar files?. May be you are giving the wrong path location.

Answer (score 0):

Try with another version of "spring web.jar".